# Stuck in my induction proof

Tags: induction

I am at a step in my induction proof where I need to show that:

$\frac14(k+1)^{2}k^{2}+(k+1)^{3}$

is equal to

$\frac14(k+2)^{2}(k+1)^{2}$

Which I can't really seem to figure out how to. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac14(k+1)^2k^2+(k+1)^3=\frac14((k+1)^2k^2+4(k+1)^3)&=\frac14((k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4))\\
&=\frac14(k+1)^2(k+2)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to understand where the factor 4 comes from in the second step.

Comment: Ops. Sorry I missed the plus sign within the first equation. The $4$ appear while adding up the two terms $\frac14(k+1)^2k^2$ and $\frac44(k+1)^3$ which together yields to $\frac14((k+1)^2k^2+4(k+1)^3)$

Comment: Thanks, I think it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$(k+1)^2(\frac{1}{4}k^2+k+1)=\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)=…$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac14(k+1)^{2}k^{2}+(k+1)^{3}=   (k+1)^2   \big ((1/4) k^2 +k+1)  $$

$$=        (k+1)^2 \big ( (1/4) (k^2+4k +4)\big ) =(1/4)(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2$$